# Laravel specific folders act as root

Tags: php, laravel

I came across problem in laravel, cant find a solution, maybe you could help me out.

I have many folders with HTML documents that are linked (same folder as HTML) with css, some of css are inside assets, includes, root folder.

[image: Folders structure]

I can access these html files by going `https://website.com/live/1/index.html` but the problem is that laravel sees css and other files in website root folder `https://website.com/assets/app.css` instead of `https://website.com/live/1/assets/app.css`

I think I could find a solution in htaccess by typing `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(assets/.+)$ /live/1/$1` but then it means, that I have to create and edit htaccess everytime for a new folder.

Maybe someone has any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default asset URL with your .env file and add this

```
ASSET_URL=https://website.com/live/1
```

it would change your `asset()` method behavior

Comment: But then it changes my primary website assets. I have primary website which is accessed from "web.php" and then I would like "live" folder act as separate root.

For example if I use "ASSET_URL=https://website.com/live/1", then all pictures in my "www.website.com" disappear.
The only solution I found is to delete /live/ and put all folders inside public folder, then it works as intended.

Comment: Then, how about use URL::to("/live/1") it would refer to "website.com/live/1"